# Win 7 black screen and mouse cursor after boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, drivers, graphics-card, mouse

After booting my custom PC the screen stays black. It starts with a "beep- tone", then everything runs as usual until the blue welcome-screen appears. After that the screen turns black and only the mouse cursor is displayed. After a while the screen saver turns on.

Because of this issue I setup the PC newly. I made every proposed update. So everything was ok and I started installing my programs again. I shut down the PC for a day and started it again on the other day and the same issue occurs as mentioned above.

I've just made some internet recherche and found out that it might be a graphic driver issue, so I checked the driver via automatic driver recognition of the AMD site which tells me that the driver for my components is ok.

ctrl+alt+del shows me the task manager, also saved mode is possible (with and without network driver).

So what could be the reason? Is it possibly a hardware defect? How can I check out where the failure is?

windows 7
Radeon HD 5770
AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 640 Processor
4096 MBytes DDR3; 668.3 MHz

Comment: Safe Mode works normally?

Comment: yes even with network

Comment: can you run `sfc /scannow`?

Comment: This is the scann funktion within F8? I tryed this with no result.

Comment: sorry I thought about the repair your computer function. entering  sfc/scannow in the cmd asks me to restart my computer because of a outstandong system repair. No matter how often I restart.

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever heard of Windows Death Screen (black). This happens only in windows.Possible reasons video drivers. Mac and Linux are good. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/why-is-my-screen-black-when-i-start-windows-7

Comment: i've never heard about this. I'll try this and give a feedback.

Comment: After restarting explore.exe the Desktop appears as usual. I'v already installed the current driver. After restarting the PC the problem aoccurs again. The registry value is set on explorer.exe. Unfortunately there are no restore points also because the PC has recently been set up.

Comment: Yes this is an issue and Microsoft is still working on or atleast. Two best possible suggestions would be check your video cards and the other would be Reload OS.More importantly try the safe mode options suggested by Microsoft. Hope helps.